# Is it Possible to have an ASP.NET Application in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook-2010

Users need to fill out an access request and once they are done and hit the submit, it emails the request to their supervisor. 
Is it possible to email the entire form(with the user data and also to be filled fields by supervisor) in an email so that the supervisor can select accept and the change would be reflected in a SQL database from Outlook itself?

Answer (score 0):

Emailing the form can be done.  Writing an Outlook add-in can also be done.  But you'll save yourself a lot of time if you just write an "approval" page in your web app and send a link to this page in the email to the supervisor.  You can put any information you want in the email, of course.

ETA:  But to actually suggest a solution:  you could send an email that included a hyperlink, that included identifying information in the query string, and use that as a way of signalling to a web page or web service that the request should be approved.  You'd have to work out something with security and authentication, of course, so that not just anybody could call that page and approve the request.